# Replace image urls(absolute instead of relative) by using filter in single page

Tags: plugins, rss, images, paths

I'm using a plugin called [Foliopress WYSIWYG](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/foliopress-wysiwyg/). While using this plugin, images found in the_content loop using relative image path instead of absolute paths. So all the feed images looks broken.

This plugin stores images in `http://mysite.com/images` folder instead `wp-content/uploads` folder. So i would like to use filter to replace relative path.

I mean if any img src file looks like `/images/2010/03/example.jpg` then it should be filtered and replaced with `http://mysite.com/images/2010/03/example.jpg`

Can anyone give me the snippet?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it, you may have to fiddle with the `preg_replace()` to get it to work the way you need, but the concept (and, more importantly imo, the regex, is there).

```
if( is_single() ) {
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse44503_filter_content' );
}

function wpse44503_filter_content( $content ) {
    $regex = '#src=("|\')'.
        '(/images/(19|20)(0-9){2}/(0|1)(0-9)/[^.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp|jpeg))'.
        '("|\')#';
    $replace = 'src="'.get_site_url( $2 ).'"';

    $output = preg_replace( $regex, $replace, $content );

    return $output;
}
```

That's untested, and I wrote it right into the solution box, so make sure you debug thoroughly and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However i'm getting this error. `syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'` Can you fix it? This is the line where i'm getting that error `$replace = 'src="'.get_site_url( $2 ).'"';`

Comment: try `'src="'.get_site_url().'$2'"'`. Like I said, you're gonna have to tinker with it a bit.